# How can I disable any users (except root) from executing `wall`?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a Linux server with about 20 users. They were using `wall` command which is annoying. I have root permissions and still want to be able to use it myself. But, how can I restrict normal users from using the Linux `wall` command?

Comment: mesg n , can deny message that work for individual user, but I looking for a way to disable/deny all users except root on this host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to deny access to for all users, then you might want to remove the setgid bit on `/usr/bin/wall`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/wall
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root tty 13884 2011-08-09 12:15 /usr/bin/wall
$ sudo chmod g-s /usr/bin/wall

$ echo foo | wall
```

You should always be able to wall yourself and root should be able to wall everyone, but user A won't be able to broadcast to the rest of the users.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would find out why they are using wall, and then ask them to use a more appropriate service such as write or talk.  If they are not willing to comply, then BOFH.  Technology is not an answer in these cases.

Comment: May be the person who use wall command just want to have some fun without noticed that the rest users suffered. Most of the user don't know about linux much , so they cannot deny message by themselve.